# entry.remove(success, fail) calls success, but doesn't remove image

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova

I am trying to delete an image in phonegap (iOS), so i call:

```
window.resolveLocalFileSystemURI(imageURI, ok, no);
```

this calls the ok-function

```
function ok(entry) {
            alert("Deleting: " + entry.name);
            entry.remove();
        }
```

So everything goes as planned, but my image still show up in my library. What am I doing wrong?

full source:

```
window.resolveLocalFileSystemURI(imageURI, ok, no);
        function ok(entry) {
            alert("Delete file entry: " + entry.name);
            entry.remove(pictureRemoved, notRemoved);
        }
        function pictureRemoved(){
            alert('removed');
        }
        function notRemoved(){
            alert('not Removed');
        }
        function no(error) { alert
        ("resolveFileSystemURI failed: " + error.code); }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with below code:

```
//Delete file 
window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, 
    function(fileSys) { 

        fileSys.root.getFile(imageURI, {create: false}, 
            function(file) {
                file.remove(pictureRemoved, notRemoved);                                                  
            }, no);
    }, no);
```

It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Add the file plugin. It will work.